# how inflate layout navigation view in MainActivity.kt

Tags: android-layout, kotlin, navigation-drawer

i try this:

```
val user = "false"
    if (user == "true"){
        navHead.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        navLeft.inflateMenu(R.menu.nav_menu)
    }else{
        navHead.visibility = View.GONE
        navLeft.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.colorGrey))
        navLeft.itemTextColor = (ColorStateList.valueOf(resources.getColor(R.color.colorWhite)))
        navLeft.inflateMenu(R.id.layout)
    }
```

layout.xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DenemeDenemeDenemeDenemeDenemeDenemeDenemeDenemeDenemeDeneme" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and error:  Resource ID #0x7f090070 type #0x12 is not valid

if user is true i should do inflate menu but if user is false i should do menu visibility gone and  include my layout.xml

Comment: `navLeft.inflateMenu(R.id.layout)` A layout is not a menu.

Comment: Yes i know but my ask how set layout visibility